# How to hide attachment icon from bot framwork

Tags: c#, botframework

I am new in Bot Framework, need to hide Attachment icon from Chat window in Bot framework through c#.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a custom Webchat.

The sources are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

You can have a look to `Shell.tsx` [file](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Shell.tsx#L86), where the button (called `wc-upload-input`) is located:

```
<div className={className}>
    <input id="wc-upload-input" type="file" ref={ input => this.fileInput = input } multiple onChange={ () => this.onChangeFile() } />
    <label className="wc-upload" htmlFor="wc-upload-input">
        <svg>
            <path d="M19.96 4.79m-2 0a2 2 0 0 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zM8.32 4.19L2.5 15.53 22.45 15.53 17.46 8.56 14.42 11.18 8.32 4.19ZM1.04 1L1.04 17 24.96 17 24.96 1 1.04 1ZM1.03 0L24.96 0C25.54 0 26 0.45 26 0.99L26 17.01C26 17.55 25.53 18 24.96 18L1.03 18C0.46 18 0 17.55 0 17.01L0 0.99C0 0.45 0.47 0 1.03 0Z" />
        </svg>
    </label>
    <div className="wc-textbox">
        <input
            type="text"
            className="wc-shellinput"
            ref={ input => this.textInput = input }
            autoFocus
            value={ this.props.inputText }
            onChange={ _ => this.props.onChangeText(this.textInput.value) }
            onKeyPress={ e => this.onKeyPress(e) }
            onFocus = {() => this.onTextInputFocus()}
            placeholder={ this.props.listening ? this.props.strings.listeningIndicator : this.props.strings.consolePlaceholder }
        />
    </div>
    <label className={sendButtonClassName} onClick={ () => this.onClickSend() } >
        <svg>
            <path d="M26.79 9.38A0.31 0.31 0 0 0 26.79 8.79L0.41 0.02C0.36 0 0.34 0 0.32 0 0.14 0 0 0.13 0 0.29 0 0.33 0.01 0.37 0.03 0.41L3.44 9.08 0.03 17.76A0.29 0.29 0 0 0 0.01 17.8 0.28 0.28 0 0 0 0.01 17.86C0.01 18.02 0.14 18.16 0.3 18.16A0.3 0.3 0 0 0 0.41 18.14L26.79 9.38ZM0.81 0.79L24.84 8.79 3.98 8.79 0.81 0.79ZM3.98 9.37L24.84 9.37 0.81 17.37 3.98 9.37Z" />
        </svg>
    </label>

    <label className={micButtonClassName} onClick={ () => this.onClickMic() } >
       <svg width="28" height="22" viewBox="0 0 58 58" >
            <path d="M 44 28 C 43.448 28 43 28.447 43 29 L 43 35 C 43 42.72 36.72 49 29 49 C 21.28 49 15 42.72 15 35 L 15 29 C 15 28.447 14.552 28 14 28 C 13.448 28 13 28.447 13 29 L 13 35 C 13 43.485 19.644 50.429 28 50.949 L 28 56 L 23 56 C 22.448 56 22 56.447 22 57 C 22 57.553 22.448 58 23 58 L 35 58 C 35.552 58 36 57.553 36 57 C 36 56.447 35.552 56 35 56 L 30 56 L 30 50.949 C 38.356 50.429 45 43.484 45 35 L 45 29 C 45 28.447 44.552 28 44 28 Z"/>
            <path id="micFilling" d="M 28.97 44.438 L 28.97 44.438 C 23.773 44.438 19.521 40.033 19.521 34.649 L 19.521 11.156 C 19.521 5.772 23.773 1.368 28.97 1.368 L 28.97 1.368 C 34.166 1.368 38.418 5.772 38.418 11.156 L 38.418 34.649 C 38.418 40.033 34.166 44.438 28.97 44.438 Z"/>
            <path d="M 29 46 C 35.065 46 40 41.065 40 35 L 40 11 C 40 4.935 35.065 0 29 0 C 22.935 0 18 4.935 18 11 L 18 35 C 18 41.065 22.935 46 29 46 Z M 20 11 C 20 6.037 24.038 2 29 2 C 33.962 2 38 6.037 38 11 L 38 35 C 38 39.963 33.962 44 29 44 C 24.038 44 20 39.963 20 35 L 20 11 Z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16691719)

Comment: @ʙᴜᴅɪ my answer was aligned to the level of the question. But ok I will edit

Comment: My first comment was automatically generated from the Review queue, where I recommended deletion on your initial post. P.S., I was not the downvoter, but thank you for editing your answer to include relevant code.

Comment: I know the review processes, no problem. I was just a bit upset by the quality of the question but still decided to provide an answer, hence the initial limited version

Comment: @durgeshgupta if it is helpful please accept the answer

Comment: @ Nicolas, i m new in stack overflow, how to accept the answer

Comment: See `Help`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers says `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.`

Comment: how to end typing in bot framework using c# in webchat channel ? no need to show cursor in text area

Answer (score -1):

Just refer to this article:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.d.hide-upload-button-styling

Here's the code:

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
  styleOptions: {
   hideUploadButton: true
 }
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```